# How to replaceAll special characters in a string?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

So to remove all the spaces in my string. I did a method that is consists of

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

I was wondering if there was a command to remove and special character, like a comma, or period and just have it be a string. Do i have to remove them one by one or is there a piece of code that I am missing?

Comment: May not be the perfect duplicate example, but this question has been asked dozens of times.

Answer (score 19):

You can go the other way round. Replace everything that is not word characters, using negated character class:

```
message = message.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
```

or

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Both of them will replace the characters apart from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you want to replace the underscore too, then use:

```
[\\W_]
```

Answer (score 13):

Contrary to what some may claim, `\w` is *not* the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\w` also includes all characters from all languages (Chinese, Arabic, etc) that are letters or numbers (and the underscore).

Considering that you probably consider non-Latin letters/numbers to be "special", this will remove all "non-normal" characters:

```
message = message.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

\w is the same [A-Za-z0-9_] which will strip all spaces and such (but not _).  Much safer to whitelist whats allowed instead of removing individual charecters.